# Converting IPhone timestamps

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I extracted the iphone database with the gps and wifi data.
It seems that the apple timestamp is a special timestamp (313167962.508283).

How can I convert this to the linux timestamp or a real date?
If possible i want to convert it with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is in seconds since January 1. 2001. (ref: http://petewarden.github.com/iPhoneTracker/#2)

```
   $time = mktime('', '', '', 1, 1, 2001) + $appletime;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the result of [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Which would make it seconds since Jan. 1st 2001 UTC, your example would be '2010-12-04 15:05:02'(-ish, I dropped partial seconds).

In php

```php
$time = mktime('', '', '', 1, 1, 2001) + $secondsSince;
```